# Is this relationship between the centroid of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and their Gram matrix correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

If
$$
\mathbf{P} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{p}_1 \\
\mathbf{p}_2 \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{p}_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\},\mathbf{p}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and if
$$
\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{P}^T
$$
is the Gram matrix of $\mathbf{P}$, then according to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04310):

> ...considering the constraint that the centroid of the points is located at the origin, $\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0}$, which leads to $\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$.

My questions are:

1. How does $\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$?
2. If we require that $\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0}$, then why is it not necessary that
   $$
   \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}
   $$
   instead of $\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$? Since
   \begin{align}
   \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} &=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{p}_1^T & \mathbf{p}_2^T & \cdots & \mathbf{p}_n^T
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   \vdots \\
   1
   \end{bmatrix} \\
   &= \mathbf{p}_1^T + \mathbf{p}_2^T + \cdots + \mathbf{p}_n^T
   \end{align}
   which is the same as
   $$
   \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k
   $$
   up to the transpose operation.

Comment: As you observed: $\sum pK=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $P^T1=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $X1=0$. The authors left out the middle step

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the conditional statement $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0} \implies \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$$ be bi-conditional instead? $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0} \iff \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0} \iff \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}$$

Comment: @mhdadk Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0} \iff \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}
$$
then left-multiplying both sides by $\mathbf{P}$ yields
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P} \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} &= \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
and so
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{0} \iff \mathbf{P}^T \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0} \iff \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{0}
$$